# Java Eclipse SDK cannot build project and I don't know why

Tags: java, eclipse, git, macos, gradle

I have just downloaded a brand-new installation of Eclipse Mars on my 'El Capitan' Mac and am trying to collaborate with a colleague on a project of theirs. However, I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried importing it as a .git file, a gradle file, a general Java file, and the result is usually the same. Gradle will run, but Project->Build is always grey (gray?), and I cannot build or run the project. When I go to properties for the project, there are no settings for "Java" (This is a Java project, and Eclipse correctly seems to have detected the markup.)

Here's a screenshot of where I expected "Java" to be: [image: No Java??]

When I go to Project->Build, "Build Project" is greyed (grayed?) out. 
[image: grayed out]

Lastly, when I right-click on Gradle, shouldn't there be some Gradle options here too? 
[image]

Some of the things that I have tried so far / to recap, I have tried:

1. importing my project as a git project
2. importing my project as an 'existing code' project
3. importing my project as a gradle project
4. I have made sure that git / gradle are installed.

Is there anything else I can do? Is there anything else I forgot to do? Is there anything that I did wrong?

*Edit: Adding the .project file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>test</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleprojectbuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleprojectnature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: Did you try Run as and then select Gradle? Also, did you check that the plugin for gradle is installed? I am using Maven, so when I try to build and run, I right-click the mouse on the project, then run as Maven build

Comment: There are several different Eclipse downloads, some contain Java, others don't.

Comment: I don't have that option, @m.aibin

Comment: @greg-449 I'm pretty sure I've got the Java one, but how can I tell for sure?

Comment: Show us the contents of the '.project' file for the project.

Comment: @greg-449 Added, thanks for all of your help so far, aibin too :)

Comment: The .project file shows that the project is not a Java project so you don't get any Java specific entries in the Properties.

Comment: @greg-449 Oh really? I'm new to Eclipse... How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The .project file shows that the project is not a Java project so you don't get any Java specific entries in the Properties.

One way to fix this is to edit the .project file to:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>test</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleprojectbuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleprojectnature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

You may need to Refresh the project after changing this.

This has added the Java build command and the Java project nature.

You should then have the Java pages on the project properties.